# OpenShift / OKD Specify URL for each Pod Replica

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd, strimzi

I am new to the Open shift / OKD.
I am running Strimzi on top of open shift.

I have deployed an application which includes Rest API. 
This Application has Rest Api and One can control Producer and Consumer from rest Api.
I have replicated the POD of my application to 3.

To have better control we want to have fire query to each pod replica personally. ex. pod-replica1 of my application `kafka-testing` to start the producer.pod-replica2 of my application `kafka-testing` to start the consumer and so on.

How can we access the each pod-replica individually to perform the test? We can't create multiple application with same source.

let me know if something is not clear.

Thanks A Lot

Comment: I guess you need headless service (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) and individual routes for each service endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If your application also runs in OpenShift, run `oc get svc` to find names of each broker. Note these names are only accessible inside OpenShift cluster.

For example, if `oc get svc` returns:

```
> oc get svc
NAME                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
my-cluster-kafka-0                    ClusterIP   172.30.210.241   <none>        9094/TCP                     109d
my-cluster-kafka-1                    ClusterIP   172.30.39.25     <none>        9094/TCP                     109d
my-cluster-kafka-2                    ClusterIP   172.30.93.193    <none>        9094/TCP                     109d
```

, you can access `kafka-0` by `my-cluster-kafka-0` or `my-cluster-kafka-0.<pod_namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

If your application runs outsides OpenShift, please configure strimzi [external listeners](https://strimzi.io/docs/0.11.1/#external_listener). Among the three options to setup [external listeners](https://strimzi.io/docs/0.11.1/#external_listener), `NodePort` may be easier if you run on-premise OKD.

Comment: We only Have a Single Application Deployed with multiple Replica. I updated the Question let me know Any thing else which can be helpful

Comment: I guess you need headless service (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) and individual routes for each service endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `statefulset` with a `headless` service, then you can access each pod with `$(podname).$(service name).$(namespace).svc`

read more about `stable network id` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id)

Comment: Can access each pod with $(podname).$(service name).$(namespace).svc  outside open shift cluster?